# Advance Plucking Lessons

Tags: guitar, learning, technique, plucking

Check this out.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LA-GadOp9sA (In this video it is not me)

I like plucking a lot. Most of the time I play Blackmoor's night. I can play several famous Blackmoor's Night track, including Under a Violate Moon, Catherin Howards Fate, Possum Goes to Prague etc.

But When I saw this plucking I was mesmerized! How do I even get started to get my control to this level?

Here I want to mention that, my first guitar lesson was One Last Breath - Creed, it took a long time to complete it. But, I just love plucking so much.

So, is there any suggesting about how can I focus more about plucking. Basically I am an amateur who is looking for some advanced lessons for improving my plucking skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a teacher or if not get hold of a copy of The acoustic guitar bible by Eric Roche. This is a brilliant advanced level book and will keep you busy for some time.

Comment: Can you suggest any particular guitarist's lesson who would be good for plucking?

Comment: If you want Internet lessons I reckon Justinguitar & Jamplay are the best, there are also some Tommy Emmanuell lesson but not many on you tube.  But for home study Like I said  The Acoustic Guitar Bible is the one.  Check out the author Eric Roche on Youtube a brilliant guitar player and teacher.